# how to fix bug found on meltdown/spectre?

Tags: 18.04, bug-reporting, debugging

linux found bug on meltdown and spectre .
what i do for fix this problem ?
discription in text note in home directory is ;
 *bug: cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass*
 ;

file name is :hs_err_pid***.log

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying there is a file in your home directory containing such text? What is the file name?

Comment: file name is hs_err_pid***.log

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019596/can-anybody-tell-me-details-about-hs-err-pid-log-file-generated-when-tomcat-cras?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: i see ,but is not answer about this bug !

Comment: You can upvote the question and answer on that 6 1/2 year old bug, as I will.